# Displaying Hashed values from Rails/Neo4j

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am migrating from Postgres to Neo4j and I trying to display the results of my Neo4j query is a partial.

home_controller.rb

```
  def index                
    @products = Product.as(:p).where(featured: True).limit(12).pluck(:p)
    respond_with(@products)
  end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="products">
    <%= render partial: "/products/product_display", collection: @products, as: :product, locals: { product_class: "col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 product" } %>
  </div>
</div>
```

_product_display.html.erb

```
:
  <div class="product-title">
    <h5><%= link_to product.product_name, product_detail_path(product) %></h5>
  </div>
:
```

The problem I seem to be getting is that it returns the following:

```
[#<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>, #<Product>]
```

and I get:

```
undefined method `product_name' for #<Product>
```

I'm sure this is just part of grasping the basic understanding for Rails but it was okay using Postgres.

I am a novice and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you don't have a property assigned for `product_name`.  Since Neo4j is schemaless it can't read the list of columns from the database like ActiveRecord does.  What if you did this?

```
class Product
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :product_name
end
```

The `property` method sets up things like `product_name` and `product_name=` methods which set the property for persisting.

Also for migrations if you've already got ActiveRecord models set up you should check out this project:

https://github.com/neo4jrb/neo4apis-activerecord

It doesn't require ActiveRecord models, but they make the import cleaner.  You still need to set up your Neo4j models like I suggested above.

I'm one of the maintainers of both `neo4apis-activerecord` and the `neo4j`/`neo4j-core` gems, so happy to answer any other questions either here or on Gitter

Comment: You star! I knew it would be something ridiculously easy. I need a kicking sometimes!! :) Thanks